# How to correctly nest tables in DynamoDb

Tags: python, database, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I'm attempting to store information from a decompiled file in Dynamo.

I have all of the files stored in s3 however I would like to change some of that.

I have an object id with properties such as a date, etc which I know how to create a table of in dynamo. My issue is that each object also contains images, text files, and the original file. I would like to have the key for s3 for the original file in the properties of the file:

Ex: FileX, date, originalfileLoc, etc, images pointer, text pointer.

I looked online but I'm confused how to do the nesting. Does anyone know of any good examples? Is there another way? I assume I create an images and a text table. Each with the id and all of the file's s3 keys. Any example code of how to create the link itself?

I'm using python boto btw to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stay between the limits of Dynamodb of 64Kb per item.

You can have one item (row) per file.

DynamoDB has String type (for file name, date, etc) and also a StringSet (SS) for list of attributes (for text files, images).

From what you write I assume you are will only save pointers (keys) to binary data in the S3. 
You could also save binary data and binary sets in DynamoDB but I believe you will reach the limit AND have an expensive solution in terms of throughput.

Comment: so I can't say this table column a references another table directly?

Comment: i'm not sure why you want this type of joins. Perhaps you should re-consider dynamodb

Answer (score 0):

From what you described, I think you just need to create one table with hashkey. The haskey should be object id. And you will have columns such as "date", "image pointer", "text pointer", etc.

DynamoDB is schema-less so you don't need to create the columns explicitly. When you call getItem the server will return you a dictionary with column name as key and the value.

Being schema-less also means you can create new column dynamically. Assuming you already have a row in the table with only "date" column. now you want to add the "image pointer" column. you just need to call UpdateItem and gives it the hashkey and image-pointer key-value pair.